# var with underscore won't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a JQuery plugin that I use regularly with eBay sellers, I put in their eBay seller ID and I get results showing their live eBay listings. I have a seller who has an underscore in their ID name, and the JS does not work for them, I'm not sure why or how to fix it, what do I need to do?

JS:

```
//Define seller ID
var UserID = "rvinyl_inc";
var settings = {
    "UserID":UserID,
    "loadingClass": "loading",
    "serviceUrl": "http://ebay.sunandfuninoc.com/ebay.php"
};


// Featured Items
$(".x-tb-title-feat").loadFeatured( $.extend({}, settings, { 
    "service": {
        "keyword": null,
        "category": 2875468016,
        "num": 4,
        "operator": "AND"
    }
}) );
```

The HTML is really simple, just a title bar div and the dynamic content renders directly after it:

```
<!-- auto featured items -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">include("http://ebay.sunandfuninoc.com/js/jquery.featuredproducts.min.js")</script>
<div class="x-tb-title x-tb-title-feat" title="Featured Items"><!-- sp --></div>
```

I don't get any error messages on the JS from my source code validator. The same script, with the same filters, works perfectly if I use any other UserID name that does NOT contain any special characters. I tried backslashing before the underscore, just in case, but that didn't help.

Comment: Are you escaping (or perhaps *not* escaping) the underscore character inside the plugin?  This might cause problems with finding the User Id in the eBay system.

Comment: Do you mean this - I tried and it still doesn't load: `var UserID = "rvinyl[_]inc";`

Comment: Probably not that.  If you wrote the jQuery plugin, can you post the code that builds the final URL to load the data?  What you're looking for is some sort of JavaScript escape call, converting some characters into URL-encoded form.

Comment: Oh, okay - I didn't write this plugin (if I did I'd probably know how to fix it! JS is not my specialty) - here it is: (http://ebay.sunandfuninoc.com/js/jquery.featuredproducts.min.js)

Comment: I don't see any explicit call to escape the URL.  This one is beyond me other than to suggest some research into handling URL escaping.  Perhaps the providers of the plugin could help?

Comment: Unfortunately he isn't available to support it anymore. Will look for "url escaping" q&a and see what I can find, thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the http://ebay.sunandfuninoc.com/ebay.php script? It should receive the underscore without problems, but then do something wrong. Check your network panel for the request to that url, and show us the response.

Comment: Yes I do - I wasn't sure how to paste the whole thing, so it's here: (http://ebay.sunandfuninoc.com/ebay.txt)

Comment: Is this the part that needs adjusted? `if( isset( $_GET["UserID"] ) && isset( $_GET["service"] ) ){

  $UserID = $_GET["UserID"];
  $sqlsafe_UserID = mysql_real_escape_string($UserID);
  $service = $_GET["service"];
  $authToken = array(`